# concat yesterdays date with a specific time

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I need to create a query that looks at yesterdays date but at a specific time.  I would like the time portion to be in the 'hh24:mi:ss' format as this is how the search field is formated.

when I run this query it works:

```
where date_dt = to_date('2013-12-13' || '19:16:08','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

but when I try to query for yesterday it does not:

```
where date_dt = to_date(trunc(sysdate)-1 || '19:16:08','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

I get zero rows returned.  any idea what im doing wrong here?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where date_dt = to_date(to_char(sysdate-1, 'YYYY-MM-DD') || ' 19:16:08', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

should work.